# Why my function is not work with receiver

Tags: kotlin

```
class A {
   var initFunc: B.() -> Unit
   fun initWith(func: B.() -> Unit) {
        this.initFunc = func
    } 
    fun test() {
      val b = B()
      b.apply{ initFunc }
    }
}

class B {
    fun init() {...}
}
...
val a = A()
a.initWith{ init() }
a.test()
```

I found the function init inside B is never called during the debug of test(), what's wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line of your code:

```
b.apply{ initFunc }   // doesn't do anything
```

Does not call a function, it just gets the reference to a function and does nothing with it.  Add `()` to call the function.

```
b.apply{ initFunc() } // works!
```

But technically if you are just wanting to change the context (receiver) of a call, use `with` instead of `apply`:

```
with (b) { initFunc() }
```